# Programmatically open PrimeNG calendar in modal popup

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-calendar, primeng-dialog

How to make PrimeNG calendar at open state by default in modal popup ? Or how to trigger click event to open PrimeNG calendar which is in modal popup by typescript ?

If I used in HTML itself, it triggers the click event to open calendar by `showoverlay()`, but when using in modal popup, since popup is not in DOM element, it shows error as `showoverlay()` is not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add a `Viewchild` to your calendar so that you can manipulate it to open it programmatically.

Then, inside your method which opens the popup, call the `showOverlay` method on your calendar object to open it.

Finally, surround this last line of code with a `setTimout` to delay its call.

**HTML**

```
<p-dialog header="Title" [(visible)]="display" [width]="500" [height]="500">
    <div class="row" style="height:300px;">
        Select a date
        <p-calendar #myCalendar [(ngModel)]="value"></p-calendar>
    </div>
</p-dialog>

<button type="text" (click)="showDialog()" pButton icon="fa-external-link-square" label="Choose date"></button>
```

**Ts**

```
@ViewChild('myCalendar') calendar;

display: boolean = false;

showDialog() {
    this.display = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.calendar.showOverlay(this.calendar.nativeElement);
    }, 0);
}
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsxgvu)

Comment: When using p-dialog, had an error that p-dialog is not known element, when analysed, it needs to upgrade my angular-cli version, but if i did that, it affected some other components. So can you tell me that how to achieve the Programmatically open PrimeNG calendar in modal popup in ngx-bootstrap or else is there any way to use p-dialog without upgrade?.

Comment: Have you imported `DialogModule` in your `AppModule` file ? Which version of PrimeNG do you use ?

Comment: yes, imported but missed to add in imports, it works now. Thank you!